# Copy specific text, including formatting, from message to new message

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I parse specific text, including formatting, from a message into a new Outlook message?

I have code which splits an incoming message by line to find an email address found within the body of the message.

It then creates a new message, the recipient of which is the email address found in the original message:

```
Sub AutoReply(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim vText As Variant
Dim vAddr As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim sAddr As String
Dim sName As String
Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim olOutMail As Outlook.MailItem

With Item
    'Get the text of the message
    'and split it by paragraph
    vText = Split(Item.Body, Chr(13))
    'Examine each paragraph

    For i = 1 To UBound(vText)

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            sAddr = ""
            For j = 1 To UBound(vItem)
                sAddr = sAddr & vItem(j)
            Next j
            If InStr(1, UCase(sAddr), "HYPERLINK") > 0 Then
                vAddr = Split(sAddr, Chr(34))
                sAddr = vAddr(UBound(vAddr))
            End If
        End If

    Next i

    Set olOutMail = Application.CreateItem(0)

    With olOutMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor 'Edit the message body
        'Set a range to the start of the body (thus preserving the signature)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range(Start:=0, End:=0) 
        .To = sAddr
        .Subject = "Subject Goes Here"
        'personalise the reply message body
        oRng.Text = "Message body goes here"

        .Display 'This line is required
        'add .Send after testing if you are happy 
        'not to check the message before sending.
        '.Send 
    End With

    Set olOutMail = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Can I adapt the above to parse text between two specific points from the original message into the new message?

The original message looks like this:

```
Dear Mr Bloggs,

Random text here random text here random text here random text here random 
text here random text here random text here random text here random text here 
random text here random text here random text here random text here random 
text here random text here random text here random text here random text here 
random text here random text here random text here random text here.

Some text here (will always be the same text)

This is the text I need to parse to new message this is the text I need to 
parse to new message this is the text I need to parse to new message this is 
the text I need to parse to new message this is the text I need to parse to 
new message.

More text here (will always be the same text)
```

---

The below script has been pointed out to me. I don't know how to use functions though and I'm muddling my way through as best I can. How do I implement in my code?

```
Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource As String, strLabel As String)
Dim intLocLabel As Integer
Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
Dim intLenLabel As Integer
Dim strText As String

' locate the label in the source text
intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
    intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
    If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
        intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
        strText = Mid(strSource, _
                        intLocLabel, _
                        intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
    Else
        intLocLabel = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
    End If
End If
ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```

---

I've got it working with a similar function because the first bit of text that is always the same is different to the second bit of text that is always the same. I used the below which defines the end string as well:

```
Function ParseTextLineDown(strSource As String, strLabel As String, strEnd As String)

Dim intLocLabel As Integer
Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
Dim intLenLabel As Integer
Dim intLocEnd As Integer
Dim strText As String

' locate the label in the source text
intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
If intLocLabel > 0 Then
    intLocEnd = InStr(strSource, strEnd)
    intLocCRLF = intLocEnd
    ' testing message boxes
      ' MsgBox ("First IF" & vbCrLf & intLocLabel & "=intLocLabel, " _
        & intLocCRLF & "=intLocCRLF, " & intLenLabel & "=intLenLabel, ")
      ' MsgBox (strText)

    If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
        intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
        strText = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel, intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
    ' testing message boxes SECOND IF
      ' MsgBox ("Second IF" & vbCrLf & intLocLabel & "=intLocLabel, " _
        & intLocCRLF & "=intLocCRLF, " & intLenLabel & "=intLenLabel, ")
      ' MsgBox (strText)
    Else
    ' testing message box ELSE
      '  MsgBox (strEnd & " " & " " & intLocLabel & " " & intLocEnd)
        strText = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
    End If
End If
ParseTextLineDown = (strText)

End Function
```

Is it possible to insert the captured text into a table or to keep the formatting of the copied data, because it is already in a table?

Comment: Yes, its feasible. Search for (will always be the same text)
and copy text from that point up to the next (will always be the same text)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I just don't know how to do that. I'm not that adept with VBA and not from a programming background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA outlook body string search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/vba-outlook-body-string-search)

Comment: Thank you @zpontikas I have updated my question.