# Auto export information of outgoing emails to an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to automate and capture the following details from sent mail items into an Excel sheet using VBA.

[image]

When I send an email with a particular subject let's say "Index Coverage Request", the following details should be saved in the Excel sheet.

[image]

I think I should use something like this to extract specific text from the email.

```
For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
    If InStr(1, olMail.Body, sFilterStart, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        aExtract = Split(olMail.Body, sFilterStart)
```

Code that attempts to save:

- recipient email address
- sender email address
- sent date and time
- Email body

```vb
Public WithEvents objMails As Outlook. Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objMails = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFoldersentitems).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objMails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strExcelFile As String
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nNextEmptyRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnB As String
    Dim strColumnC As String
    Dim strColumnD As String
    Dim strColumnE As String

    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set objMail = Item
    End If
 
    strExcelFile = "E:\Email\Email Statistics.xlsx"
 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Error <> 0 Then
       Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile)
    Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 
    nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
    strColumnB = objMail.ReceipentEmailAddress
    strColumnC = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    strColumnD = objMail.SentTime
    strColumnE = objMail.Body
 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = nNextEmptyRow - 1
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnB
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnC
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnD
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnE
  
    objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:E").AutoFit
 
    objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can  you explain what the issue is with your code? An error message? If so, what line throws the error?

Comment: `xlUp` is not defined?  Are you using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: @Tim Williams: Yes i am using option explicit, also I have attached two snapshots for reference. one is representing the email body and the one beneath it represents the outcome I need in the excel sheet.

Comment: @BigBen : The code is not serving the purpose at the moment, as I am still not clear how to add a specific subject line in the code and also how to get the required details from the email body to excel sheet. please refer the attached snapshots for better understanding.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Excel object model in your Outlook VBA project?

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes i have added Microsoft outlook 16 object library

Comment: What about *Excel* ?  `xlUp` is an Excel constant - it's not defined in Outlook VBA so without a reference to the Excel object library you should get a compile-time error on that.

Comment: ...in any case though, your screenshot doesn't match your code, and it's unclear exactly what the problem is you're having.  `If objMail.Subject = "Index Coverage Request" Then` might be a good place to start.

Comment: Hi Tim, i have defined that as well. the problem what line of code should I add to get the desired set of content from the email body to excel sheet. Hope you have gone through the attached screenshots.

Comment: For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
If InStr(1, olMail.Body, sFilterStart, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
aExtract = Split(olMail.Body, sFilterStart)
I think I should use something like the above to extract specific text from the email

Answer (score 0):

Text in a certain format, can be retrieved as described in [Search structured text in Outlook body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body).

If feasible you could try modifying your mail. Perhaps add a section with appropriate labels.

With a more freeform, but still consistent, format a solution is a lot more work.

```
Hello,

I am contacting you from data science division of xyz company. We have provided your contact details by ABC client in order to request access to the pricing data for the below indices:

SGBNKAM

SGNKREIT

SGBNKA3

These indices are to be used as a reference in the valuations out for ABC client on behalf of 123 client.
```

You possibly have left too much for others to code. Nevertheless, it would be difficult to describe this possible solution in words.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()
    objMails_ItemAdd ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Sub

Private Sub objMails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objMail As mailItem
    
    Dim strExcelFile As String
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Dim nNextEmptyRow As Long
    
    Dim bodyLines() As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim strlineI As String
    Dim lenLineI As Long
    
    Dim strlineJ As String
    Dim lenLineJ As Long
    
    Dim strThese As String
    Dim lenThese As Long
    
    Dim strOnBehalf As String
    Dim lenOnBehalf As Long
    Dim posOnBehalfOf As Long
        
    Dim strRaised As String
    Dim lenRaised As Long
    
    Dim strEndClient As String
    Dim lenEndClient As Long
    Dim posEndClient As Long
    
    Dim bIndexDone As Boolean

    If Item.Class = olmail Then
    
        If Item.Subject <> "Index Coverage Request" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Set objMail = Item
        
    End If
 
    strExcelFile = "E:\Email\Email Statistics.xlsx"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ' temporary error bypass for a specific purpose
    Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Err: " & Err
        Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    ' Return to normal error handling (or fail "with no errors")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile)
    Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 
    nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    
    'review the available mailitem properties in the Object Model documentation
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = "objMail.ReceipentEmailAddress"  '?
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("F" & nNextEmptyRow) = "objMail.SentTime"               '?
       
    bodyLines = Split(objMail.Body, vbCrLf)
    
    For i = LBound(bodyLines) To UBound(bodyLines)
                                    
        strlineI = bodyLines(i)
        
        If Len(Trim(strlineI)) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "line " & i & ": " & strlineI
        End If
        
        If InStr(bodyLines(i), "These indices are to be used") Then
                                
            lenLineI = Len(strlineI)
            Debug.Print "lenLineI: " & lenLineI
        
            strThese = "These indices are to be used as a reference in the valuations out for "
            '...........123456789_0123456789_123456789_123456789_12345678_123456789_123456789_
                
            strOnBehalf = " on behalf of"
                        
            lenThese = Len(strThese)
            Debug.Print "lenThese: " & lenThese
                
            posOnBehalfOf = InStr(bodyLines(i), " on behalf of")
            Debug.Print "posOnBehalfOf: " & posOnBehalfOf
                
            lenRaised = (posOnBehalfOf - 1) - lenThese
            Debug.Print "lenRaised: " & lenRaised
                
            strRaised = Mid(strlineI, lenThese + 1, lenRaised)
            Debug.Print "strRaised: " & strRaised
            objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strRaised
                
            lenOnBehalf = Len(" on behalf of")
            Debug.Print "lenOnBehalf: " & lenOnBehalf
                        
            posEndClient = posOnBehalfOf + lenOnBehalf
            Debug.Print "posEndClient: " & posEndClient
                
            lenEndClient = lenLineI - posEndClient - 1
            Debug.Print "lenEndClient: " & lenEndClient
                
            strEndClient = Mid(strlineI, posEndClient + 1, lenEndClient)
            Debug.Print "strEndClient: " & strEndClient
            objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strEndClient
                
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    For i = LBound(bodyLines) To UBound(bodyLines)
                                    
        strlineI = bodyLines(i)
        
        If Len(Trim(strlineI)) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "line " & i & ": " & strlineI
        End If
                
        If InStr(bodyLines(i), "I am contacting you from") Then
        
            For j = i + 1 To UBound(bodyLines)
                
                ' All lines following "I am contacting you from"
                '  not containing "These indices are to be used"
                '  must be the index numbers
                If InStr(bodyLines(j), "These indices are to be used") = 0 Then
                    If Len(Trim(bodyLines(j))) > 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "line " & j & ": " & bodyLines(j)
                        objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = bodyLines(j)
                        nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                        Debug.Print "nNextEmptyRow: " & nNextEmptyRow
                    End If
                        
                Else ' "These indices are to be used" found
                    bIndexDone = True
                    Exit For
                        
                End If
  
            Next
                
        End If
        
        If bIndexDone Then Exit For
            
    Next
    
    objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:F").AutoFit
 
    objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
End Sub
```