# Change the subject with text from body

Tags: vba, outlook

I have emails with a generic subject line like this:
***You have received a new notification from ABC***

The email body has text like this:
Team: NA Inventory
Division: American Division

I have a rule to identify the "You have received a new notification from ABC" to then run a script to change the name with: `objMail.subject = "test done"`

I'd like to use the body text to rename the subject line like this:
**You have received a new notification from ABC -- American Division -- NA Inventory**

Comment: May this helps you https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-quick-methods-create-new-emails-template-outlook-vba/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search structured text in Outlook body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how to extract the keyword form mail body text.
If so, use `VBScript.RegExp` to extract keywords from mail body `objMail.Body`, as follows.

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "\bTeam: ([^\n\r\f]*)"
    Set reMatch = .Execute(objItem.Body)
    team = reMatch(0).SubMatches(0)
    .Pattern = "\bDivision:\s*([^\n\r\f]*)"
    Set reMatch = .Execute(objItem.Body)
    division = reMatch(0).SubMatches(0)
End With
objItem.Subject = ".... --- " & team & " --- " & division
```