# Pull Email Address from the body and Autoreply

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I receive cancellation notifications of client bookings:

> Cancellation Notification
> Dear Sir/Madam,
> The reservation listed below has been cancelled.
> For any additional support, please contact your Service Manager or Support Center support@------.com
>
> - Booker Name: ------
> - Address:
> - Email: mail.mail@mail.mail.com
> - Phone: +-- ----

I'm trying to pull the email address of the client and auto-reply with a template.

```vb
Sub SendNew(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Reg1 As Object
    Dim M1 As Object
    Dim M As Object
    Dim strAddress As String
 
    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "(([\w-\.]*\@[\w-\.]*)\s*)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
    End With

    If Reg1.Test(Item.Body) Then
        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(Item.Body)
        For Each M In M1
            strAddress = M.SubMatches(1)
        Next
    End If

    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\---\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\can.oft")
    objMsg.Recipients.Add strAddress
    ' Copy the original message subject
    objMsg.Subject = "Cancel" & Item.Subject
 
    ' use for testing
    objMsg.Display
    ' objMsg.Send
End Sub
```

It pulls "support@------.com" not the one I want.
Also it copies the same subject of the notification email.

All client email addresses have the same domain. I want to pull email address with a certain domain only.

Comment: Why don't you change your regex pattern to capture email address that has the said domain name since it's fixed? something like `[\S]*\@domain\.com`

Comment: Alternatively you could search for whatever text is next to **Email:**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body

Comment: Did not work may be because the domain contains two words? Also new email window used to pop up, it stopped. When I changed the domin